# Android alternative to Briss? (To split PDF pages.)

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-editor

There's a very good desktop application called [Briss](https://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/). It's used when a PDF has several pages per page and you need to split them into separate pages. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, this program allows batch processing of all the pages in the document. That is a requirement. I don't want to have to individually crop each page.

I'm traveling at the moment and I only have my phone. Is there an Android app that can do the same thing? It does not have to be free.

Comment: I've not tried any, but be welcome to take a look at my list of [PDF Tools](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf#group_117). Some of the apps there have the feature to split PDF files.